# ASP.Net DropDownList event handler even when user selects the same item

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` that allows users to make selections. These selections result in a table being populated.

This all works fine when users select different values. However, I woudl like to refresh the table even when the user selects the same value.

Does anyone know what event on the *ASP.Net* `DropDownList` that I can use for this?

My DropDownList looks like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a refresh `Button` next to the `DropDownList` and write your logic inside its `Click` event handler too.

It would be easier to the user to click the `Button` than selecting the same item from the `DropDownList`.

Comment: Out of the answers linked below and this question, this is the best answer. ie: It cannot be done directly via asp.net and code-behind as there is no trigger to issue a postback. The user has to click something else to force the dropdownlist to "reset".

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

[DropDownList annoyance: same value won't trigger event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318926/dropdownlist-annoyance-same-value-wont-trigger-event)

Comment: Thanks but my values are all unique. In my case when the user selects "option 1" then clicks "option 1" again I want the event handler for the DropDownList to be triggered.