# ASP.NET combo selectedIndexChanged event is not called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have written a `selectedIndexChanged` event for combo on a web page in ASP.NET (C#).
This event is not called. When in debug, the control does not go into the code this event. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoPostBack` property to `true`.

If it doesn't help, check this answer: [DropDownList annoyance: same value won't trigger event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318926/dropdownlist-annoyance-same-value-wont-trigger-event)